# How can I convert a .YUV image to the other imge format like png and jpg in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

1. How can I convert a YUV format frame to the image format like png,jpg in matlab?
2. How are the image formats like png, jpg are stored in matlab? (For example a YUV format is a `1*N` vector containing the `Y,U,V` information for the consecutive frames: Y1,U1,V1, Y2,U2,V2,...)

Answer (score 3):

About 1.

There aren't build-in function in MATLAB for converting YUV frames to common images. But there are some hand-maded resources like this: 
[MathWorks website](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6318-convert-yuv-cif-4-2-0-video-file-to-image-files)

About 2.

Loaded in MATLAB images presents in arrays.
For example I just save image in two different formats - jpg, and png.
And load them using `imread`:

```
a1 = imread('Graph.jpg');
a2 = imread('Graph.png');
whos a1
whos a2
  Name        Size                  Bytes  Class    Attributes

  a1        843x1114x3            2817306  uint8              

  Name        Size                  Bytes  Class    Attributes

  a2        843x1114x3            2817306  uint8
```

There are some interesting opportunities for some of the formats: for example, you can load PNG in this way: `[A,map,transparency] = imread('image.png')`. You can find this all in [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html).

Hope It helps!